# Will using two availability zones in ec2 introduce network paritions?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, celery, django-celery

Currently I am using one availability zone in my ec2 launch config. It is important that I don't get network partitions in my app, as rabbitmq does not handle network partitions well when clustering and HA is used (which I am using).

I am very fuzzy on the concept of network partitions. Would it be safe for me to use two availability zones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The different Amazon EC2 Availability Zones are in different physical locations.  While the connections between availability zones are quite good, it is still a WAN connection.

From the RabbitMQ docs

> RabbitMQ clusters do not tolerate network partitions well. **If you are thinking of clustering across a WAN, don't.** You should use federation or the shovel instead

(emphasis mine)

https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html

In short, a 1 minute or so interruption in connectivity will cause a network partition to be created.  While this would be an unusual event for EC2, it can and sometimes will happen.

Comment: I see, so then sticking to one availability zone should be alright, correct?

Comment: If you are only in one availability zone, you are at risk if that data center is impacted by some sort of event.  It does happen from time-to-time that an availability zone encounters significant problems, though it is quite rare.  If you can accept an outage during such rare events, one zone is fine.  If you cannot, you need a plan to shift processing to a second zone.

Comment: I appreciate the input Eric. My application can definitely accept the level of uptime aws has, and I would rather rink some rare service interruptions than deal with network partitioning, so I will stick with one zone.

Comment: One thing to consider is to have infrastructure setup in a different availability zone, but have all or most of the servers paused (thus almost free).  If an availability zone has protracted downtime (earthquake / hurricane / etc), you could quickly ramp up a new environment.  You still need to consider how you ensure current data in the alternate zone.  Depending on your needs, you might restore from a DB backup (losing things that happened since the backup), or you might leave a small DB server running in the alternate zone and replicate to it.

Comment: Ah this would actually work very well for me, as the data I am working with is stored in S3 and is not based on real time user feed or anything (it is 'permanent' data). Because of this I would not have to worry about obtaining lost data. I was not aware I could have instances stopped.

Comment: S3 is already automatically mirrored across availability zones, so sounds like you have a good solution.  I think when you create an instance, there is a checkbox indicating whether the default shutdown behavior is to terminate or pause the instance.  Make sure you select pause if they still ask you to choose.  Been a while since I did this myself.